# JavaFX 8, VBox DragEvent - why can't I select the VBox Children

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, java-8, focus

Hey I'm currently working on my masterthesis and have a poblem to witch I can't find a solution. 
I hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Well I created this UI:

[image]

Here I'm trying to make the elements in "Properties" dragable and drop them in the lower TextFlow Node.
The Drag and Drop itself seems to work already. I tried it with one Test-Label.

[image]

But for some reason I cannot manage to reproduce that with the children in the "Properties" VBox.

This is how I tried it:

```
 private void fillScrollPane(Content content, ScrollPane scrollPane) {
    Map<String, Object> map = content.getProperties();
    scrollPane.setPickOnBounds(false);
    VBox root = new VBox();
    scrollPane.setContent(root);

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        Object value = map.get(s);
        if (value == null || value.toString().equals("[]") || value.toString().equals(""))
            continue;
        Label t = new Label(s + " : " + value.toString() + "\n");
        t.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            Dragboard db = t.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
            // Store node ID in order to know what is dragged.
            clipboardContent.putString(t.getId());
            db.setContent(clipboardContent);
            event.consume();
        });

        root.getChildren().add(t);
    }

}
```

but instead of draging the children in the VBox it just seems to select the whole VBox on mouseclick ..

So in short: 
Order is like this
Scene -> ScrollPane -> VBox -> Label 
and I want to select the label with a drag event. Direct on Scene it does work but not the VBox.

Does anyone have an idea what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it out, JavaFX does not give autogenerated IDs. And without them Drag and Drop seems not to work.